# Join tables in MySQL using RAND() and LIMIT

Tags: mysql

I need extract for these MySQL tables one row to `tbl_gallerypics` and two rows to `tbl_youtube` and I have tried this Join query but the output is not correct.

My MySQL tables below.

Thanks in advance.

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT
    Pic,
    Link
FROM
    `tbl_gallerypics` A
JOIN `tbl_youtube` B
ORDER BY
    RAND()
LIMIT 1;
+---------------+-------------+
| Pic           | Link        |
+---------------+-------------+
| gallerypic7   | wwKxirmcoUg |
+---------------+-------------+
1 row in set
```

[image: <code>tbl_gallerypics</code>]

[image]

Comment: There is no way you get what you want with just this join. Also you are limiting your results to 1 row `limit 1` you are doing a cartesian plan. You need to be a little more specific. What would be the results you expects. Also what is the relation between these two tables ?

Comment: You miss the `ON` cause in your join.

Comment: It's kind of tough to understand what you expect to happen, since `tbl_gallerypics` doesn't seem to contain "gallery22.jpg" and `tbl_youtube` doesn't appear to contain "-U9A4KnSmW0".

Comment: I need join these two tables and extract one row to tbl_gallerypics and two rows to tbl_youtube; these tables don't have relation.